# Using a one-shot thermal cutoff as a hardware key

Tags: computer-hardware

I want to include a hardware key in a sealed circuit that can be deactivated once the device is programmed, avoiding reprogramming again. I think of using a small current fuse or a one-shot thermal cutoff that can be burned and will not conduct current afterwards. I have not found any components that are manufactured for this particular purpose.

Does anyone know of a solution that has been tested? Thanks!

Comment: They are not usually manufactured separately since separate components are easier to bypass.  These mechanisms tend to get built into chips.  This forces someone to replace the whole chip (usually more expensive than bypassing a component).

Comment: The microcontroller I want to use does not have an internal fuse to disable reprogramming, but the device does have an external seal that invalidates its use if it is broken. The case is hermetically sealed, so it is not possible to remove a tape or other media that can be used as a hardware key. The fuse or thermal cut-off is a good idea because these are burned by activating a transistor that allows the flow of a high current. When the fuse is open, the voltage at its terminals is greater than zero, acting as a blocking signal.

Comment: Supposing your physical seal and the rest are correct and you just need to burn something out, any appropriately rated fuse would work.  Expose the terminal that you need to, and fry the fuse after programming.  Aim for a rating lower than what your chip's terminals can handle but above what your programming state needs (usually extremely small), or you may just need additional resistor(s) to draw the extra current away from the chip (for the frying step).  If you add what the microcontroller is, someone might be able to suggest a variant with a builtin protection option, or a fuse rating.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't switch microcontrollers to one which *can* disable re-programming?

Can you switch to one that can self-write? If so, use a custom bootloader to reprogram and you don't have to break out the programming pins at all.

Can you include a tab in the design that can be pulled out after programming? If so you could have that ground out the programming mode trigger pin.